# Hyperledger Composer returns error No ledger context for GetState

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am currently developing a transaction in Hyperledger composer. This transaction is going to create 2 different Assets : Asset A and Asset B.
Asset A has a field with the type Asset B. So I first need to create Asset B and then create Asset A with a link to Asset B. I have managed to implement the logic, after a few struggles. Now the peer returns the following error :

> 2018-10-10T14:06:14.022Z [5ad2a944] DEBUG    :NodeDataCollection       :add()                     > assetAIdValue, {"$class": "mynamespace.assetA","assetAId": "assetAIdValue","assetAFieldX": "assetAFieldXValue","assetB": ["resource:mynamespace.assetB#assetBIdValue1", "resource:mynamespace.assetB#assetBIdValue2"]},"$registryType":"Asset","$registryId":"mynamespace.assetA"}, false
>
> (node:17) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: Error when creating AssetA with id assetAIdValue
>
> Error: [5ad2a944]No ledger context for GetState. Sending ERROR

Here is my model

```
namespace mynamespace

/**
 * Definition of createAssetA transaction
 */
transaction createAssetA{
  o String assetAId
  o String assetAFieldX
  o AssetB[] assetB
}

/**
 * Definition of AssetA asset
 */
asset AssetA identified by assetAId{
  o String assetAId
  o String assetAFieldX
  --> AssetB[] assetB
}

/**
 * Definition of assetB asset
 */
asset AssetB identified by AssetBId{
  o String assetBId
  o String assetBFieldX
  o String assetBFieldY
}
```

Here is my logic.js

```
/**
* Creates the assets assetB and assetA
* @param {mynamespace.createAssetA} createAssetA - the AssetA to create
* @transaction
*/
function createAssetA(createAssetA) {
    return getAssetRegistry('mynamespace.AssetB')
        .then(function (assetBRegistry) {
            // Add all the AssetBs to the AssetB registry
            assetBRegistry.addAll(createAssetA.assetB)
                .then(function(){
                    addAssetA(createAssetA);
                }, function(error) {
                    throw new Error ('Error while creating AssetBs' + '\n' + error);
                } );
        });
}

/**
 * Function to add assetA asset to registry
 * @param {*} createAssetA - The createAssetA Transaction containing the assetA info
 */
function addAssetA(createAssetA){
    return getAssetRegistry('mynamespace.AssetA')
        .then(function (assetARegistry) {
            var newAssetA = castcreateAssetATxToAsset(createAssetA);
            return assetARegistry.add(newAssetA).catch(function (error) {
                throw new Error ('Error when creating AssetA with id ' + createAssetA.id + '\n' + error);
            });
        });
}

/**
 * Casts the createAssetA transaction as a AssetA Asset
 * @param {*} createAssetA - The transaction createAssetA to cast
 * @returns {mynamespace.AssetA} the AssetA Asset with the info from the createAssetA param
 */
function castcreateAssetATxToAsset(createAssetA){
    var factory = getFactory();
    // Create a new instance of AssetA class from the mynamespace namespace with the id createAssetA.id
    var newAssetA = factory.newResource('mynamespace', 'AssetA', createAssetA.id);
    newAssetA.assetAFieldX = createAssetA.assetAFieldX;
    newAssetA.assetB = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < createAssetA.assetB.length; i++) {
        var assetB = factory.newRelationship('mynamespace', 'assetB', createAssetA.assetB[i].id);
        newAssetA.assetB[i] = assetB;
    }
    return newAssetA;
}
```

And here is the content of my request

```
{
 "$class": "mynamespace.createAssetA",
 "assetAId": "assetAIdValue",
 "assetAFieldX": "assetAFieldXValue",
 "assetB": [
  {
   "$class": "mynamespace.assetB",
   "assetBId": "assetBIdValue1",
   "assetBFieldX": "assetBFieldXValue",
   "assetBFieldY": "assetBFieldYValue"
  },
  {
   "$class": "mynamespace.assetB",
   "assetBId": "assetBIdValue2",
   "assetBFieldX": "assetBFieldXValue",
   "assetBFieldY": "assetBFieldYValue"
  }
 ]
}
```

If anyone new the cause for such an error he would save my day !

**Another question** :
This error is only visible when I look at the chaincode containers. Anybody knows how I can make them visible from the Composer REST Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a view `return` statements from your code in the promise chains, but TP functions support async/await which I would highly recommend you use instead of promise chains as it makes the code so much easier to read. For example (note, not tested)

```
/**
 * Creates the assets assetB and assetA
 * @param {mynamespace.createAssetA} createAssetA - the AssetA to create
 * @transaction
 */
async function createAssetA(createAssetA) {
    try {
        const assetBRegistry = await getAssetRegistry('mynamespace.AssetB');
        await assetBRegistry.addAll(createAssetA.assetB);
        await addAssetA(createAssetA);
    } catch(error) {
        throw new Error ('Error while creating AssetBs' + '\n' + error);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to add assetA asset to registry
 * @param {*} createAssetA - The createAssetA Transaction containing the assetA info
 */
async function addAssetA(createAssetA){
    try {
        const assetARegistry = await getAssetRegistry('mynamespace.AssetA');
        const newAssetA = castcreateAssetATxToAsset(createAssetA);
        await assetARegistry.add(newAssetA);
    } catch(error) {
        throw new Error ('Error when creating AssetA with id ' + createAssetA.id + '\n' + error);
    }
}

/**
 * Casts the createAssetA transaction as a AssetA Asset
 * @param {*} createAssetA - The transaction createAssetA to cast
 * @returns {mynamespace.AssetA} the AssetA Asset with the info from the createAssetA param
 */
function castcreateAssetATxToAsset(createAssetA){
    const factory = getFactory();
    // Create a new instance of AssetA class from the mynamespace namespace with the id createAssetA.id
    let newAssetA = factory.newResource('mynamespace', 'AssetA', createAssetA.id);
    newAssetA.assetAFieldX = createAssetA.assetAFieldX;
    newAssetA.assetB = [];
    for (let i = 0; i
```

Comment: Thank you very much !
Indeed this synthaxe is easier to read, I didn't know it was supported since all the tutorials are written with the one I used previously